# SQL Report Builder Same Key has already been added; Update with Cte

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have declared a table with the following variables:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    [Counter] int              
    ,Period Date primary key
    ,VanMe float
)
```

And I have done some steps to set the VanMe.

The following is the With and the Select statement where the error is occurring:

I narrowed this down to the first part in With because for Report Builder cte.Period and #tmp.Period is considered the same two keys. After I changed that and used the Select statement it still gave me the same error.

Is there a way I can calculate the Avg in the With statement and just call

```
Select * from #tmp.
```

I tried it with the update it did not work at all. It gave me null for the VanMeAvg and the other Avg variables.

Please HELP!

The error that I get is this:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that there are `2 columns` with the `same name` in the `select` query .Column names should be `distinct` .
The repeated columns are

```
HfxMetric
,HfxMetric = AVG(HfxMetric) Over (Partition by [Counter])
```